# How to locally cache network drive in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, cache, mapped-drive

I work remotely and connect to a shared network drive through a VPN. This works great for the most part. However, when there are problems with the connection (either the internet on my end or at my office) it prevents me from being able to work at all. Is there a way in windows 8.1 that I can locally cache some of the folders on the network drive so that they are available offline?

I have looked around and found how to do it in windows 7 but the "make available offline" option doesn't appear to exist in 8.1.